# Prevent construction/initialization of array elements in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, clang

I have the following declaration (yes, its using the runtime array length extension)

```
Iterator traversal_stack[depth];
```

My problem is that the compiler attempts to initialise array members. In fact, this code does not compile, because `Iterator` has no public default constructor. While I understand where this behaviour comes from, in my case it is really unwanted, because the access pattern to the array 
guarantees that:

1. an array element will be written to at most once and
2. no element will be ever read without being written.

Any violation from this pattern means that the algorithm is messed up. Below is a pseudocode that illustrates how the array is used (it's essentially a heavily optimised stack for traversing a balanced tree)

```
Iterator traversal_stack[depth]; 
auto current_node = root;
auto current_level = 0;

// traverse the tree, looking for a suitable insertion point
// within every node, record visited nodes (vie the iterator struct)
while(current_level < depth) {
   // find the optimal insertion entry (pointed to by the iterator) 
   auto iter = as_branch(current_node).iterate();
   iter = find_best_insertion_point(iter, to_inserted_object);

   // record the visited node in the stack
   // a value is pushed onto the stack exactly  once!
   traversal_stack[current_level] = iter;

   // get to the next level of the tree
   current_node = iter.node_for_entry();
   current_level += 1;
}

// ... insert the data into the found terminal node

// now unroll the stack, adjusting the node metadata
current_level -= 1;
while(current_level >= 0) {
  // the element of the array is necessarily initialized
  // by assignment in the previous loop
  auto iter = traversal_stack[current_level];
  insertion_state = adjust_node_metadata_for(iter);

  current_level -= 1;
}
```

I know that I could just provide the default constructor and be done with it, but I would really like to avoid it. Besides possible (but probably less important) performance considerations, the biggest issue with a default constructor is that it would have to introduce some sort of default invalid state, messing up the iterator semantics big time.

So, my question: can I declare the array like that leave the values completely undefined? I am ok if the solution is specific to Clang using the latest C++1z draft + custom extensions.

Comment: Please provide some actual code, perhaps a simplified testcase, to demonstrate what you are talking about, so that we can more easily understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector` and add `Iterator`s as needed?

Comment: ...or wrap it in a `std::stack`, which seems an intuitive choice for something called `traversal_stack` and relieves you from implementing `push()` / `pop()` semantics...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid adding your own default constructor? It could simply be empty.

Comment: `=-`? is that meant to be `-=`?

Comment: I don't want to use std::vector or stack because they both have horrible performance (in this case — its a very tight, perf-critical loop). Don't see much point un using a dynamic container for a static array with very predictable allocation and access patterns. @Galik: because the default constructor does not make any sense for the iterator. After all, the iterator has to iterate something. A default value for an iterator is by definition invalid. And having invalid iterator states is not helpful in my case.

Comment: @MrMobster But you **want** an invalid iterator so doesn't adding an empty default constructor solve your problem?

Comment: @Scheff: even if the array were not initialised, I don't see how the algorithm can result in the UB. It never reads uninitialised memory. And if it does, then something went horribly wrong already so UB is acceptable (there are tons of precondition tests to avoid that).

Comment: @Galik: no, invalid iterators is exactly what I don't want. Every iterator ever referenced or otherwise used by the algorithm is always valid. Again, every read location has previously been explicitly initialised with a valid iterator.

Comment: Also `std::vector` is not slow, its as fast as an array (because it is an array inside) and it does exactly what you want. It allocates its array using `malloc` to prevent the constructor running and then performs *in place* construction as needed.

Comment: @MrMobster If you create an array without running the constructors you already have **invalid** iterators and you said that is what you want.

Comment: @Galik: please try running a small malloc() thousands time per second and tell me how your code will perform. Of course I tested `vector` performance. Also, I am never iterating the array itself, so I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @MrMobster `std::vector` doesn't run `malloc` thousands of times. Simply call `std::vector::reserve` and it will call `malloc` only once for the entire array.

Comment: @Galik: obviously its the algorithm itself that has to run thousands of times per second. I don't really understand why we are arguing about this TBH. I respect that you seem to have issues with the way I do optimisations. But that was not my question.

Comment: Or you could use `malloc` yourself?

Comment: Maybe use a mempool and/or custom allocator, or a statically allocated vector fed into algo  by reference.  In general, std::vector is fast enough for almost anything. Stating that is horribly slow is just insulting.

Comment: @ErikAlapää as I have said, I did my benchmarks. I am designing a heavily cache-friendly optimised data structure.  If the average  tree traversal time is in the ballpark of 100nanoseconds, the overhead of `malloc` and `free` is *very* noticeable (in fact, they reduce the performance by the factor of 2-3).

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at `alloca` function? Of course, in general, its use is discouraged, but that does not say that in your specific case it does not solve your problem...

Comment: So are you needing to allocate this array more than once? I thought the array was create once and the algorithm accessed it multiple times?

Comment: @Galik: the array is created every time the algorithm is run. Its local traversal state after all. I could of course avoid the initialisation overhead by using a single copy of the array, but that would most likely defeat many helpful compiler optimisations, in addition to being horrible coding style :)

Comment: If you know the maximum size then perhaps you could use a `thread_local static` array inside your algorithm function? That should be fast and thread safe. It is ideal that you don't care what it contains on function entry.

Comment: @MrMobster: Like I said, have you considered pre-allocation or some simple mem pool scheme? That gives more room for special-case optimization than general malloc/new.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: that seems to me like a total overkill for this situation. After all, all I want is to have a small algorithm-local buffer with as little overhead as possible. Using pre-allocated storage for this purpose strikes me as bad code design. Furthermore, I don't understand why such measures should even be necessary. In fact, "safe" languages such as Rust and Swift have well-documented facilities for working with uninitialised memory — so I am a bit surprised that my question is seen as this controversial in the context of C++

Comment: @MrMobster I agree with you that a VLA is still useful in some situations (and supported in C++ by gcc), probably yours is one of them. I just resented the general, sweeping statement that std::vector is slow. STL in general is probably the fastest and best container library in the world, and std::vector is the fast, cache-friendly workhorse of the STL.

Comment: ...or claiming that `std::stack` has "horrible performance" when it's just a functionality wrapper for whatever container you're applying it to.

Comment: I thought I was very clear  clearly wrote — any container with dynamic (malloc) memory allocation has unacceptable performance *in this particular scenario*. I never claimed that STL dynamic containers are generally slow, just that they are not appropriate when all you want is a very fast temporary buffer with a known maximal size. Stack-based allocation literally involves a single CPU instruction — you can't beat this with a dynamic container, no matter how you optimise it. Frankly, I don't even understand why this is a point of discussion.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use VLA and uninitialized object.

A way is to use std::aligned_storage for creating uninitialized memory blocks, and then cast it to a reference to array.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Iterator {
  Iterator() = delete;
};

int main() {
  int length = 10;
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Iterator), alignof(Iterator)> memory_blocks[length];
  auto &array = reinterpret_cast<Iterator (&)[length]>(memory_blocks);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is so far the only answer that attempts to answer my question. Thanks for `std::aligned_storage_t`, I was not aware of it. But shouldn't it be `typename std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Iterator), alignof(Iterator)>::type` instead?

Comment: `std::aligned_storage_t` is `typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Iterator), alignof(Iterator)>::type`. Notice the removed `_t` in my comment, I believe that you made a typo.